# Move a Git repository to another directory

Tags: php, git, github, repository

I want to move a git repository to a sub-directory which is there in its present root folder.
Let me explain the things first.

I have `Git` repository `testing` in `$HOME/repos/` (contains **PHP** code-base).
Now i want to move `testing` into `$HOME/repos/php/` where `php` will be sub-directory which i want to create (anyway `php` directory is not a git repository)

My questions are

- if i do above explained move then does this effect my `testing` repository ?
- Does this effect any branches or commits or uncommitted changes in `testing` repository ?

Comment: Just move all the code including .git directory from testing to php directory and it will work without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving a repository to a different directory should have no effect on the repository. Simply move everything as you would with any other kind of files, taking care to move the .git directory along with it. That .git directory is what git looks at and compares against other stuff in the project directory (wherever that .git directory lives).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Robert. I will try this.